# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (despite only rendering one component with an array of objects prop)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know similar questions have been asked before but none seem to address the nuance of this situation.

I am writing a react app that passes a prop down to a component. This prop is an array of objects. I am only rendering ONE child component and not mapping the array of objects to render many.

First, I set the state with `this.setState({ balancesMapping: balancesMapping });` balancesMapping is the array of objects.

I then construct the component to be rendered via
`<Sweep balance={this.state.balance} helpers={this.state.helpers} to={this.state.to} balancesMapping={this.state.balancesMapping}/>`

This sweep component takes the balancesMapping array and uses each element to create a `Token` component like follows:

`const tokens = this.props.balancesMapping.map((balanceObj) => {return <Token balanceObj={balanceObj} account={this.props.account} to= {this.props.to}/>});`

However, I get the following error which has been discussed before on this site:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_hex, _isBigNumber}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This doesn't make sense to me because I am merely passing the prop as an array of objects, I am not trying to create a 1:1 ratio of sweep components for each element in the array and want to pass the array down directly.

An example of the balancesMapping array of objects:

`[ { "address": "0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d", "type": "ERC721", "balance": "1610029", "decimals": 0, "name": "CryptoKitties" }, { "address": "0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d", "type": "ERC721", "balance": "1717860", "decimals": 0, "name": "CryptoKitties" } ]`

The full error message:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_hex, _isBigNumber}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the code for the components? It will make this question a lot easier to answer

Answer (score 0):

Answered here on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/mepg02/objects_are_not_valid_as_a_react_child_despite/

Since the balance BigNumber is an object, it can't be rendered directly and needs to be cast as a string or Number.